# How to enable Double-Tap to Drag in Mac OS X Catalina?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I found a few solutions how to enable this(double click and drag) feature

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13048479

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8094988

so on...

But on Catalina OS I can't find this feature...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

System Preferences → Accessibility → Pointer Control → Mouse & Trackpad → Trackpad Options…

[image]

Enable dragging → Without Drag Lock (or With Drag Lock per your preference)

[image]